# How to get selected value of dropdown when using partial view in mvc?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views, cascadingdropdown

I am using partial view to display a view inside another and the partial view has the drodown so how to get the value of that dropdown actually i want to display another dropdown based on the value of the first dropdown here is my code in detail:

partial view:

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <link href="~/Content/control.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <fieldset>
        <legend></legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CompanyID , new {@class="lbldis"})
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.CompanyID, new SelectList(ViewBag.CompanyList as System.Collections.IEnumerable, "_CompanyID", "Company"), "- Select -",new { @class = "txtbox",id="ddln" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CompanyID)
        </div>
        <br />
        <div>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.ClientID, new SelectList(ViewBag.ClientList as System.Collections.IEnumerable, "_ClientID", "Company"), "- Select -",new { @class = "txtbox" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ClientID)
        </div>
    </fieldset>
}
```

and the view where i am calling this partial view:and the name of that view is Index:

```html
<div id="tab-1">
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/PartialViews/_company.cshtml")              
</div>
```

All the dropdowns are working fine and getting the values and all but only problem is with the javascript. Please help me on where to write the javascript i.e in partial view or in Index where I am calling my partial view and how to to display another dropdown based on the value of the first one.

What I have tried so far is below:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#ddln").change(function onchange(dropdown) {
        var myindex = dropdown.selectedIndex;
        var SelValue = dropdown.options[myindex].value;
        if (SelValue == 'Client3')
        {
            var see = document.getElementById("ddln");
            see.style.display = "";
        }
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Assume these are typos, but make sure its `model => model.CompanyID` (lowercase "m", or simply `m => m.CompanyID`) and the second dropdown is binding to the same property as the first one!. You script makes no sense. Are you wanting to populate the second dropdown with clients based on the value of the selected company?

Comment: Agree with @StephenMuecke ...Also please check the id of the ddl's as element takes the name and id = to property name if not specified explicitly

Comment: If you want the selected value then its `$('#CompanyID').change(function() { var id = $(this).val(); });` but what do you want do do with it?

Comment: I am sorry i am new to mvc but i have changed the code at model=>model.clientid and i want to display client dropdown only when specific company name is selected pls hlp me on this!!  and all of you thanks for this quick reply!!

Comment: Re your last edit - why give it an different `id` attribute? (i.e. change the default `id="CompanyID"` to `id="ddln"`)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are using jquery you can handle controls of partial view from main view using on() function. Earlier (before 1.9) you could have used live() but this has been deprecated since.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $('body').on("change", "#ddln", function (evt) {

            if ($(this).val() != 'val1')  //assume if val1 is the value against which we wish to show. 
            {
                $('#ndl').show();
            }
            else
            {
                $('#ndl').hide();
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Not me, but no doubt because this has nothing to do with OP's question. (1) Event delegation is not required (the element exists in the DOM), (2) you are handling the wrong element and (3) you haven't given an answer showing how show/hide the second dropdown

Comment: hey guys this code is working : <script type="text/javascript">
        var $tt = jQuery.noConflict();
    
        $tt("#ddln").change(function () {          
                $tt("#ndl").show()
            })
    </script>                                                                                                              but the problem is when i give if condition it stops working so if you can help on that

Comment: how to write dropdownlist 1.selectedvalue.tostring() in mvc??

Comment: Event delegation is not required ,but bring no harms either. I wrote the code just with the initial question which was not quite clear. Now i have updated the answer ,which is in line with  OP's question. Please upvote it again.

Comment: Do you seriously think the first dropdown has an option with `<option value="hide">Some text</option>`?

Comment: @parth7253: your Question is not clear, if you are asking how to get this in jquery then on change event  $(this).val() will return the selected value. $(this).text() will yield the text.

Comment: @StephenMuecke: he hasn't mentioned anything so that is just a sample value  which i am expecting .Just the way you have assumed "Client3". My bad though i am terrible with naming.

Comment: I assumed "Client3" because OP code contains `if (SelValue == 'Client3')` which I think is a fair assumption. And now you have almost plagiarized my answer. And you should check what `$(this).text();` returns for a `<select>` tag!

Comment: not plagiarized by any means, it's still in line with what i answered first.I am using event delegation against your code.But we can't re-manufacture jquery syntax.

Comment: hey @Utkarsh i havent downvoted you it was some one else !!! and i dont even have that reputation to upvote you so soorry!

Comment: @parth7253: can you accept my answer. That way it will help others looking for same issue.

Answer (score 0):

To hide or display the 2nd dropdown based on a value in the first:

```
var clients = $('#ClientID');
$('#CompanyID').change(function() {
  var id = $(this).val();
  if (id == 'Client3') { // assume you want to hide it if the selected option value is 'Client3'
    clients.hide();
  } else {
    clients.show();
  }
});
```

Edit

Based on OP's last edit which changed the default `id` attribute from `id="Company"` to `id="ddln"`, the code would be modified to

```
$('#ddln').change(function() { ...
```